# Number of real roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Consider the polynomial $$P = X^4 + 2X^3 - 6X^2 + X + 1 \in \mathbb Z[X]$$

What is the number of the real roots of $P$ ?

I have found that $P$ has no rational roots ($1$ and $-1$ are not roots) and $$P(X) = Q(X)(X^2-1) + 3X-4$$ if that helps in any way.

Comment: $P(0)>0$ while $P(1),P(-1)<0$, and $P(X)\to +\infty$ as $X \to \infty$ or $X \to -\infty$, so $P$ has four real roots.

Comment: @kccu You can post as answer... haven't thought it was that easy. Thank you !

Comment: Will do. $\quad$

Comment: Sometimes wolfram alpha can be hepful: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+%2B+2x%5E3+-+6x%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+1%3D0 .

After, you can use intermediate value theorem for continious functions. Have a good day.

Comment: @scarface Thank you ! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(0)>0$ while $P(1),P(-1)<0$, and $P(X)\to +\infty$ as $X \to \infty$ or $X \to -\infty$, so $P$ has four real roots.